# Trying to create a flash app that displays photos from facebook

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, facebook, actionscript-2

I'm intending to create a flash app that pulls images from facebook and displays them in a slideshow format.

Has some here tried this? or does anyone have suggestions/advice/links on where to find information on this.

I have had a look at;
http://components.zerofractal.com/FacebookBridge/
has anyone succesfully used this? I couldn't find examples.

and

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook/
however most examples I found are created using flex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Facebook API for flash. Here is a link to it. They have a flex and a flash library.

http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/

Hope this helps.